# Custom UIElement Animations

Tags: c#, wpf, easing

Having fancy animations in WPF is quite nice so I tried to implement a generic fading animation for `UIElements` which I use for the Popups in my application. I was wondering if there was anything wrong with it, and thought about posting it here yesterday. There were indeed many things wrong at that time and I have improved the code greatly since then (I think) but there probably are still some issues with it now.

One of the first flaws I came across was that by temporarily changing the `RenderTransform` the original can get messed up if the same animation is started while another one is still playing because the `Completed` event of he first would never be called and the original `RenderTransform` is merged with a half-animated transform that comes from my disrupted animation.

To prevent this I now have a `HashSet` which is checked for the `UIElement` in question and no animation will be started if another one is still in progress, not sure if that is the best approach here.

```
namespace HB.Animation
{
    public enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }
    public enum AnimationType { In, Out }

    public abstract class UIElementAnimationBase
    {
        private static readonly HashSet<UIElement> _animatedElements = new HashSet<UIElement>();

        private AnimationType _type = AnimationType.In;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type of the animation. Default is In.
        /// </summary>
        public AnimationType Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        private UIElement _target = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the target of the animation.
        /// </summary>
        public UIElement Target
        {
            get { return _target; }
            set { _target = value; }
        }

        private TimeSpan _duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the duration of the animation. Default is 0.3 seconds.
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpan Duration
        {
            get { return _duration; }
            set { _duration = value; }
        }

        public event EventHandler Completed;

        protected void OnCompleted()
        {
            _animatedElements.Remove(Target);
            if (Completed != null)
            {
                Completed(this, null);
            }
        }

        public void BeginAnimation()
        {
            if (_animatedElements.Contains(Target))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _animatedElements.Add(Target);
            }

            BeginAnimationDetail();
        }

        protected abstract void BeginAnimationDetail();
    }

    public class FadeAnimation : UIElementAnimationBase
    {
        private Direction _direction = Direction.Down;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the direction of the animation. Default is Down.
        /// </summary>
        public Direction Direction
        {
            get { return _direction; }
            set { _direction = value; }
        }

        private double _distance = 50;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the distance of the target travels in the animation. Default is 50.
        /// </summary>
        public double Distance
        {
            get { return _distance; }
            set { _distance = value; }
        }

        private FillBehavior _opacityBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the fill behavior of the opacity sub-animation. Default is HoldEnd.
        /// </summary>
        public FillBehavior OpacityBehavior
        {
            get { return _opacityBehavior; }
            set { _opacityBehavior = value; }
        }

        public FadeAnimation(UIElement target)
        {
            Target = target;
        }

        public FadeAnimation(UIElement target, AnimationType type, Direction direction)
            : this(target)
        {
            Type = type;
            Direction = direction;
        }

        protected override void BeginAnimationDetail()
        {
            Transform tempTrans = Target.RenderTransform;

            TranslateTransform trans;
            EasingMode easing;
            double opacityTarget;
            double translateOrigin;
            double translateTarget;
            DependencyProperty translateProperty;

            switch (Type)
            {
                case AnimationType.In:
                    easing = EasingMode.EaseOut;
                    opacityTarget = 1;
                    translateTarget = 0;
                    switch (Direction)
                    {
                        case Direction.Up:
                            trans = new TranslateTransform(0, -Distance);
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.YProperty;
                            break;
                        case Direction.Down:
                            trans = new TranslateTransform(0, Distance);
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.YProperty;
                            break;
                        case Direction.Left:
                            trans = new TranslateTransform(-Distance, 0);
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.XProperty;
                            break;
                        case Direction.Right:
                            trans = new TranslateTransform(Distance, 0);
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.XProperty;
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }
                    break;
                case AnimationType.Out:
                    easing = EasingMode.EaseIn;
                    opacityTarget = 0;
                    trans = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
                    switch (Direction)
                    {
                        case Direction.Up:
                            translateTarget = -Distance;
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.YProperty;
                            break;
                        case Direction.Down:
                            translateTarget = Distance;
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.YProperty;
                            break;
                        case Direction.Left:
                            translateTarget = -Distance;
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.XProperty;
                            break;
                        case Direction.Right:
                            translateTarget = Distance;
                            translateProperty = TranslateTransform.XProperty;
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
            if (tempTrans != null) group.Children.Add(tempTrans);
            group.Children.Add(trans);
            Target.RenderTransform = group;

            DoubleAnimation animTranslate = new DoubleAnimation(translateTarget, (Duration)Duration);
            animTranslate.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = easing };
            DoubleAnimation animFade = new DoubleAnimation(opacityTarget, (Duration)Duration) { FillBehavior = OpacityBehavior };
            animTranslate.Completed += delegate
            {
                Target.RenderTransform = tempTrans;
                OnCompleted();
            };

            Target.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animFade);
            trans.BeginAnimation(translateProperty, animTranslate);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a usage example:

```
private void DisplayMode_QuickSelect_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup popup = FindResource("DisplayModePopup") as Popup;
    FadeAnimation anim = new FadeAnimation(popup.Child) { Duration = Settings.BalloonAnimationDuration };
    if (popup.IsOpen)
    {
        anim.Type = HB.Animation.AnimationType.Out;
        anim.Completed += delegate { popup.IsOpen = false; };
    }
    else
    {
        popup.Child.Opacity = 0;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    anim.BeginAnimation();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would focus on `BeginAnimationDetail` method.

- **Variable names**. I would rename at least these variables - `tempTrans` and `trans`. `tempTrans` name doesn't give me any idea what is this variable about. I would name it `originalTransform` for example - it will be enough to understand why do you add it to another transform and later resetting control's transform to this one. From `tempTrans` name it is unclear how will you use it.
- In the beginning of that method you have several variables defined and then for ~60 lines (two `switch` statements) you're setting some values to those variables. Besides the fact that some part of code is repeated there, I find it very difficult to read when variables are assigned far from the line when they were defined. I would rewrite method in order to avoid it. Algorithm could be:

  - Calculate positions of `in` and `out` points. `In = {0, 0}`, `Out` depends on `Direction` and `Distance`.
  - Decide at which point animation will start and at which point it will finish.
  - Create animations and start them.

Result (it is around two times shorter):

```
   protected override void BeginAnimationDetail()
    {
        var inPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        Point outPoint;

        switch (Direction)
        {
            case Direction.Up:
                outPoint = new Point(0, -Distance);
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                outPoint = new Point(0, Distance);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                outPoint = new Point(-Distance, 0);
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                outPoint = new Point(Distance, 0);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        Transform originalTransform = Target.RenderTransform;

        var easing = Type == AnimationType.In ? EasingMode.EaseOut : EasingMode.EaseIn;
        double opacityTarget = Type == AnimationType.In ? 1 : 0;
        Point from = Type == AnimationType.In ? outPoint : inPoint;
        Point to = Type == AnimationType.In ? inPoint : outPoint;

        var animatedTranslate = new TranslateTransform(from.X, from.Y);

        var group = new TransformGroup();
        if (originalTransform != null) group.Children.Add(originalTransform);
        group.Children.Add(animatedTranslate);
        Target.RenderTransform = group;

        var animFade = new DoubleAnimation(opacityTarget, Duration) {FillBehavior = OpacityBehavior};
        animFade.Completed += delegate
            {
                Target.RenderTransform = originalTransform;
                OnCompleted();
            };

        Target.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animFade);
        animatedTranslate.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, new DoubleAnimation(to.X, Duration) {EasingFunction = new CubicEase {EasingMode = easing}});
        animatedTranslate.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, new DoubleAnimation(to.Y, Duration) {EasingFunction = new CubicEase {EasingMode = easing}});
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this great response! I suspected that there would be a better way to handle those switches and variable initializations, very intelligent how you did that; also interesting how somewhat doing "more" by considering both axes is actually a lot shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays using auto-implemented properties is the way to go.

```
/// <summary> 
/// Gets or sets the type of the animation. Default is In.
/// </summary>
public AnimationType Type { get; set; } = AnimationType.In;
```

looks neater than

> ```
> private AnimationType _type = AnimationType.In;
> /// <summary>
> /// Gets or sets the type of the animation. Default is In.
> /// </summary>
> public AnimationType Type
> {
>     get { return _type; }
>     set { _type = value; }
> }
> ```

---

Using C# 6 (VS 2015) we can simplify the null check in the `OnCompleted()` method like so

```
protected void OnCompleted()
{
    _animatedElements.Remove(Target);

    Completed?.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

---

If we take advantage of the result of the `HashSet.Add()` method we can simplify the `BeginAnimation()` method like so

```
public void BeginAnimation()
{
    if (_animatedElements.Add(Target))
    {
       BeginAnimationDetail();
    }
}
```

but I would throw a `NullReferenceException` if `Target == null` so it will be thrown from that `public` method instead of the `protected abstract void BeginAnimationDetail()` method. IMO this is neccessary because the `Target` property is public hence it can by error be set to `null`.